# Not sure what happened! Strange TeX reaction in comment

Tags: bug, mathjax, comment

I got a strange reaction to my TeX. And I cannot recover from it or delete the comment [in the following post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415655/adding-small-correction-term-to-ode-solution)

Comment: Based on Mariano's answer I'd say that [meta-tag:support] might be a better choice of tag than [meta-tag:bug].

Comment: I have noticed this in the list of related questions: [Comments layout break if Math expression is too long](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/comments-layout-break-if-math-expression-is-too-long).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Support may be needed, but if missing a dollar sign from the end of your $\LaTeX$ screws everything up then we have a [bug]!

Comment: @user1729 If we consider this bug report (as opposed to a request for support), than it seems to me as a duplicate to the question I've posted in my previous comment. (Perhaps it could be closed as an exact duplicate in either case...?)

Comment: @MartinSleziak An exact duplicate it may be, but it is an exact duplicate of a thread from 2011...It seems like the bug has been forgotten by MSE...so maybe if this thread had been left open it might have served as a reminder?...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a missing `$`, which sometimes causes havoc.

I have fixed it.

Comment: It has certainly caused havoc for me, when I didn't have enough $.